# Triple HDMI monitors on 2018 15" Macbook Pro via three of Apple's usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, thunderbolt, hdmi

So, I have this 2018 15" 32 GB Macbook Pro 2,9 GHz 6 core i9 with Radeon Vega 20 GPU and I need to connect three hdmi monitors (@ minimum 1080p/60Hz) and three usb devices to it. Will three of the following adapters connected to my macbook do the trick?

https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF82AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=8b&fs=f%3Dadapter%26fh%3D4595%252B45b0

Comment: What monitors do you intend to use?  You only need the adapter if you intend to convert the signal.  If it’s a monitor with a USB-C connector, you won’t need it

Comment: If you intend to use HDMI (I wouldn’t), get an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271) for best results. And to maximize your connectivity, I’d get a [Thunderbolt Dock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384444/119271)

Comment: The monitors will be AOC CQ27G2U/BK which has two HDMI type A 2.0 and one DisplayPort 1.2 connections.

Comment: I have searched for thunderbolt docks & hubs, but most of them have only two ports and/or have issues in one way or another from what I can figure out online. That's why I want to use Apple's adapters and am asking if three of them should work at the same time.

Comment: The dock’s not going to give you all your monitor ports because there’s not enough display bandwidth in a single TB port, you’ll need at least two ports.  The dock will just handle the rest of your accessories better than three adapters.  And you should use the DisplayPort connections for best results

Comment: @Allen: Can I hook up three monitors using three adapaters usb-c -> HDMI or DP ?

Answer (score -1):

firs of all yes or 1 of those "CalDigit Thunderbolt 3 Mini Dock" but you can find on amazon many types of USB-c to 3 HDMI in the required resolution I'm pretty sure it will do the job

I would recommend you to buy 1 USB c to 3 usb, and 1 active adapter with 3 HDMI exits
I think this solution gives the best performers without requiring all of your computer exits, in addition,

Comment: This doesn’t answer the OP’s question as to whether the *chosen* adapter will do the job.

Comment: None of CalDigit docks have connections for three external monitors.

Comment: FYI: I didn't vote you down Omri....

Comment: You have one with 2 exits and the one you posted